# Different font color in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How to display a text in a `JTextField` ot jLabel with 2 colors.

for example:

**1** 0 **0** 0 **1** 1 **1** 0 **1**

> textField.setForeground(Color.RED ,BLUE);

Positioning individual RED for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Different font color in a JTextField

You can't achieve it with [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) instead use [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) or [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html).

Read more about [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

---

Sample code using `JTextPane` directly from [HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneStylesExample1.htm)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StylesExample12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Styles Example 1");

        // Create the StyleContext, the document and the pane
        StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
        final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(doc);

        // Create and add the style
        final Style heading2Style = sc.addStyle("Heading2", null);
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(16));
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontFamily, "serif");
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, new Boolean(true));

        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // Add the text to the document
                        doc.insertString(0, text, null);

                        // Finally, apply the style to the heading
                        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1, heading2Style, false);
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static final String text = "Attributes, Styles and Style Contexts\n"
            + "The simple PlainDocument class that you saw in the previous "
            + "chapter is only capable of holding text. The more complex text "
            + "components use a more sophisticated model that implements the "
            + "StyledDocument interface. StyledDocument is a sub-interface of "
            + "Document that contains methods for manipulating attributes that "
            + "control the way in which the text in the document is displayed. "
            + "The Swing text package contains a concrete implementation of "
            + "StyledDocument called DefaultStyledDocument that is used as the "
            + "default model for JTextPane and is also the base class from which "
            + "more specific models, such as the HTMLDocument class that handles "
            + "input in HTML format, can be created. In order to make use of "
            + "DefaultStyledDocument and JTextPane, you need to understand how "
            + "Swing represents and uses attributes.\n";

}
```

snapshot:

[image]

---

#### EDIT

As per your question try this sample code: (change it as per your requirement)

```
    // Create and add the style
    final Style redStyle = sc.addStyle("RED", null);
    redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
    redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(16));

    final Style blueStyle = sc.addStyle("BLUE", null);
    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.blue);
    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(14));
    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, new Boolean(true));

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String[] text = { "1a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "1e", "1f", "1g", "0h", "1i" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                        String s = text[i];

                        // Finally, apply the style to the heading
                        int start = pane.getText().length();
                        Style style = null;
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            style = redStyle;
                        } else {
                            style = blueStyle;
                        }
                        // Add the text to the document
                        doc.insertString(start, s + " ", style);
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Well, technique you might, if you used a `StyledDocument` within the `JTextField` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thing the same question is asked some time before. Can we do it with `JTextField` different color for each word? :)

Comment: @Braj Ok . How do it this in jTextPane!

Comment: I tested `JTextField`, it doesn't want to work, shame, it would have been a nice solution :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think in `JTextField` style works for whole text.

Comment: @Braj I think that `JTextField` simply can't support `StyledDocuments`, not matter what changes I made to the document, it always rendered in it's default color

Comment: but . my exemple . Positioning individual RED for exemple .anothen BLeu ?

Comment: change the style as per your requirement as used in sample code.

Comment: @Braj I am a beginner. Possible help me.plz
this exemple :
RBRBRBR
R→red
B→Bleu

Comment: great sample, can we have a customized document for JTextField to support ASCII + SMP characters? current version single font is applied to JTextField but sometimes, a font cannot display all characters of the JTextField, I'm looking for similar solution but no ideas.

Comment: I don't understand how to change to other portion of text to apply the style; I don't understand the first two parameters of `doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1, ...`) For example I changed it to `(0, 0, ...)` and `(12, 20, ...)` and it still gives the same result!.