# Storing value to an array with font color

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to store a value to an array and i want that value to be sent into the array with the font color red.

```
 temp = A[ first ];   
 A[ first ] = A[ i ]; //this value should be set to red color
 A[ i ] = temp;  //this too
```

So when im retrieving them and printing them on to a text field i want them to be printed in red font. and suggestions ?

Comment: What kind of "value"? Do you mean: you have an array of strings; and when displaying them, for some you would like different font colors?

Comment: they are all numbers , integers to be specific. this is actually a selection sort , i have to show each step in a textfield and whatever the two numbers which are swapped have to be marked in red.

Comment: You should change the Font. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104928/different-font-color-in-a-jtextfield

Comment: I agree with neohope. JTextfield doesn't help with font color. The EditorPane allows for using HMTL tags; so that is an easy way to work font colors, too.

Comment: Is this your homework about algorithm? You need a variable that indicate a red position when you swap 2 elements, then check to change font color when doing loop in array for displaying. It is so easy!